To match a text with a range of text cells - Google Sheets
I'm working on a project that is supposed to give me a match between a text cell ( for example "Squirrel" and an interval/range of text cells ( for example : A1= "My Squirrel is pretty", A2 = "No Animals here", B1 = "I have a cat", B2 = "I have a Squirrel" ).
What I'm trying to say is that I need to have a result as "0" ( no matches ) "1" ( there is a match ) comparing that one cell with that range of cells ( in this case the range is A1:B2 ).
What I tried to do was this function :
=IF.ERROR(IF(SEARCH("Squirrel",A1:B2)>0,1,""),"")
But with an error reffering to the interval, so I used ARRAYFORMULA :
=IF.ERROR(IF(ARRAYFORMULA(SEARCH("Squirrel",A1:B2))>0,1,""),"")
At this point I figure out that this formula is taking only the first text cell of the interval....
So now I'm blocked and I don't know how to get out of this issue.
I thought maybe to use macro, but I'm not with that...
Thank you to u all !

Which? Excel or Googlesheets? they don't play the same...

To identify the issue, please provide Minimal Reproducible Example.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use Countif with wildcard
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:B2, "*Squirrel*") > 0, 1, 0)

The asterisks (*) act as wildcards to allow characters before or after the word. The IF function checks if the COUNTIF function returns a value greater than 0. If it returns true, then the formula returns 1. Otherwise, it returns 0.

Sample Output:


Reference:

IF
COUNTIF


You saved me ! Do you know if this is possibile to do reffering to the cell ? Like : =IF(COUNTIF(A1:B2,E4)>0,1,0)  BUT working the same ? In this case I know he won't, but do you know how can I do this ?

You may try this: =IF(COUNTIF(A1:B2, "*"&E4&"*") > 0, 1, 0) you just need to concatenate using double quotes (") and add &.
If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Thank you very much !!!

@Someone If it helps, then please accept the answer (tick mark the answer).
